# How To Use Mongoose $pull Operator For To Remove Array Of Objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I'm developing an E-Commerce app which has shopping cart page and seller panel page. Seller can manage all their products from panel. And when seller deletes a product here is what I want to do:
**1. Delete The Product**
**2. Delete All Reviews Of The Product**
**3. Remove The Product From All Wishlists**
**4. Remove The Product from All Shopping Carts**.

Now I can do 1,2,3 but can't do 4th step.

---

My Shopping Cart Schema:

```
const cartSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    items: [
      {
        product: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Product" },
        seller: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Shop" },
        color: String,
        quantity: Number,
        stripePriceId: String,
        stripeProductId: String,
        selected: Boolean,
      },
    ],
    user: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "User",
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);
```

The code that runs after seller deletes the product:

```
const Cart = require("../models/shoppingCart");
await Cart.updateMany({ $pull: { "items.product": req.params.id } });
```

The code above gives an error, says:

```
Cannot use the part (product) of (items.product) to traverse the element
```

Then I tried this code and didn't work either but didn't return any errors:

```
const Cart = require("../models/shoppingCart");
await Cart.updateMany({ $pull: { items: { product: req.params.id } } });
```

None of thoose codes worked as expected. I want to delete all shopping cart items that's associated with the product that's deleted. How can I do This?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. It was because of the frontend. Wrong state management caused that problem.